# infinite square well potential

Tags: tikz-pgf

How I can draw a perfect picture of an infinite square well potential? Other words, I need something like this. Thanks for your help [image]

Comment: Welcome, please consider to add an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?

Comment: This is very easy to draw using tikz. But this is more of a "please do this for me" question, which is not liked here. Please post a more concrete question.

Comment: You must show us exactly how difficult it is to draw this figure. Add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with what you have done.

Comment: Ok  @ daleif, I just started using Tikz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess to start using and loving TikZ you need examples =p
Here is a quick draft; you may have to adjust the text and font and whatnot.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% #1    x coordinate.
\newcommand{\vandbarrier}[1]{%
    \node at (#1, 1) {\scriptsize $V = \infty$};
    \node[scale = 0.5] at (#1, 0.5) {\textbf{(Barrier)}};%
}

% #1    x coordinate.
\newcommand{\vabove}[1]{%
    \node[anchor = south] at (#1, 2) {\scriptsize $V = \infty$};%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[gray]
        (0, 0) rectangle (1, 2)
        (2, 0) rectangle (3, 2);

    \vandbarrier{0.5}
    \vandbarrier{2.5}
    \vabove{1}
    \vabove{2}
    \node[anchor = north] at (1, 0)   {\scriptsize 0};
    \node[anchor = north] at (2, 0)   {\scriptsize $L$};
    \node[anchor = north] at (3, 0)   {\scriptsize $x$};
    \node[anchor = south] at (1.5, 0) {\scriptsize $V = 0$};

    \draw[<->] (0, 0) to (3, 0);
    \draw[->]  (1, 0) to (1, 2);
    \draw[->]  (2, 0) to (2, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

If you think it's overkill to define the two commands I used, just copy paste the definition or whatever. I just don't like copypasting stuff. This way it is easier to modify, I think. Oh, and if this ends up being in a `figure` environment, you can put these two command definitions in the `figure` environment itself, right after the `\begin`, to avoid polluting the global scope.

Comment: You're welcome. Oh and maybe the vertical alignment of the `0`, `L` and `x` in the bottom part can be improved by putting a `\strut` in each of those few nodes, for example. And note that more beautiful arrows should be available in a TikZ library or something. These are just the default ones.

Comment: I noted it @ Alice M. and thank you again. It's really interesting to work with Tikz that I see. You gave me a taste to go further with TIKZ.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to Alice answer for my quantum mechanics notes:

[image: Infinite square well with some eigenfunctions]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% #1    x coordinate.
\newcommand{\vandbarrier}[1]{%
    \node at (#1, 1.3) {\scriptsize $V = \infty$};
    %
}

% #1    x coordinate.


\begin{tikzpicture}

    \fill[gray!30]
        (-1, 0) rectangle (0, 2.5)
        (4, 0) rectangle (5, 2.5);

    \vandbarrier{-0.5}
    \vandbarrier{4.5}

    \node[anchor = north] at (0, 0)   {\scriptsize 0};
    \node[anchor = north] at (4, 0)   {\scriptsize $a$};
    \node[anchor = north] at (2, 0)   {\scriptsize $x$};
    \node[anchor = south] at (2, 1) {\scriptsize $V = 0$};
    \node[anchor = north] at (2, 0)   {\scriptsize $x$};
    \node[anchor = north] at (2, 2)   {\scriptsize $\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)$};
    \node[anchor = north] at (2, 2.5)   {\scriptsize $E_n(x)=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2ma^2}$};
    \draw[<->] (-1, 0) to (5, 0);
    \draw[->]  (4, 0) to (4, 2.5);
    \draw[->]  (0, 0) to (0, 2.5);


%Functions

    \draw[red, thick, domain=0:4, samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(180*\x/4)}) ;
    \draw[blue, thick, domain=0:4, samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(360*\x/4)}) ;
    \draw[green, thick, domain=0:4, samples=200] plot (\x, {sin(540*\x/4)})  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```